# OSC communication from scsynth to python with PyOsc

Tags: python, osc, supercollider

Communication from Python to `scsynth` via `pyosc` goes well, but instead when trying to receive in Python osc messages sent from `scsynth audio server` (just `scsynth`, not `SuperCollider`), I don't understand how to get the port `scsynth` is sending to.

If I try to send a "/notify" message to `scsynth` it should reply with the sending address, but with `pyosc` I can't set a listener on the same port as the sending one, and so I can't retrieve the information that should come back.

Any suggestions about how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using `OSCClient.setServer` to tell your OSC client to use the server's socket for transmission. Here's an example to illustrate this where the OSC message is send and received at socket 8000:

```
import OSC

def handle_message(address, tags, contents, source):
    # prints out the message
    print(address)
    print(source)

server = OSC.OSCServer(("localhost",8000))
server.addMsgHandler("/test", handle_message)

msg = OSC.OSCMessage("/test", [1])

client = OSC.OSCClient()
client.setServer(server)
client.connect(("localhost", 8000))
client.send(msg)

server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am almost positive the sender and the receiver have to be on different ports. A port used for receiving cannot also be used for sending simultaneously.

regarding sending OSC messages back to pyosc I do not understand why you wouldnt use `NetAddr.new` and then `.sendMSg()`. For example (this is from the documentation on OSC Communication):

```
b = NetAddr.new("127.0.0.1", 7771);
b.sendMsg("/hello", "there");
```

More info [here](http://doc.sccode.org/Guides/OSC_communication.html).

If you wanted automatic reply from SC then you could just write a way to trigger  a responding `.sendMsg` into your OSCDef or OSCFunc, for example, which could simply wait for the initial message from python and respond with whatever you want python to get back.

Comment: This answer is about how to do send an OSC message from sclang to python - but the question is actually about sending messages from scsynth to python.

Comment: Let me emphasize a key point of my answer: regarding sending OSC messages back to pyosc I do not understand why you wouldn't use `NetAddr.new` and then `.sendMSg()`. I am well aware that those things are in sclang.

Comment: `sclang` is probably not actually running, it sounds to me like OP is running `scsynth` separately (e.g., by running `scsynth -u 57110`) and intends to completely control it with Python without having anything to do with `sclang`.

Comment: makes sense. I appreciate your answer below as it gives me some new techniques to try out (I go between python and sc often).